# I want to dynamically display submenu in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to `display submenu dynamically from database`.But  I am getting an error in line
menuBar. `FindItem(dr["ParentMenuId"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu);` that object reference not set to an instance of an object. also I am `unable to display my submenu`. What is the error please tell me.

My code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (! IsPostBack)
        getMenu(); 
}

private void getMenu()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ST015\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyData;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = "Select * from Categories";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
   // DataRow[] drowpar = dt.Select("ParentMenuId=" + 0);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentMenuId=" + 0))
    {
        menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(),
                dr["MenuId"].ToString(), "",
                dr["MenuDescription"].ToString()));
    }

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentMenuId >" + 0))
    {
        MenuItem mnu = new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(),
                       dr["MenuId"].ToString(),
                       "", dr["MenuDescription"].ToString());
        menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentMenuId"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu);

    }
    con.Close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i think `dr["ParentMenuId"]` must be coming as `null`,thats why you are getting `null reference error`..
check whether you are getting `dr["ParentMenuId"]` value....always try to check nullable values as follow....

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentMenuId=" + 0))
{
   if(dr["MenuName"]!=null && dr["MenuId"]!=null && dr["MenuDescription"]!=null)
   {
     menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(),
            dr["MenuId"].ToString(), "",
            dr["MenuDescription"].ToString()));
   }
}

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentMenuId >" + 0))
{
   if(dr["MenuName"]!=null && dr["MenuId"]!=null && dr["MenuDescription"]!=null)
   {
     MenuItem mnu = new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(),
                   dr["MenuId"].ToString(),
                   "", dr["MenuDescription"].ToString());
   }

   if(dr["ParentMenuId"]!=null)
   {
     menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentMenuId"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but seems not solved.
I've occurred with same problem.
**You've to change ParentMenuId and MenuId data type to integer from database.**